# submit form to iPay88 payment page on ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, form-submit

i have some data needed to save and populate a form clicking a button. Concurrently need to submit the form to iPay88 payment page. I tried with the code below, data saved and i got success in console.log but the form doesn't seem to submit as it is not redirect to the payment page.

```
$('#makePayment').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/OpenSupermall/public/postOrder',
    type: "post",
    data: {
      'card':$("#paymentForm input[type='radio']:checked").val()
    },
    success: function(){
      console.log('success');
      $('#paymentForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Setting async to false should work. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415740/jquery-resume-form-submit-after-ajax-call

Comment: no luck still. tried all

Comment: what console.log($('#paymentForm')) says?

Comment: actually the form will submit to 

    action='https://www.mobile88.com/ePayment/entry.asp'

which is a payment gateway link. so should it be redirect to this page?
it seems posting the value or submitting the form but no page load.
any idea?