# jQuery make a post call to another page

Tags: jquery

I have this form like so:

```
<form method="post" name="homeForm" id="homeForm" action="thank-you.php">
//...inputs here
</form>
```

and here is my jQuery:

```
$("#homeForm").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#homeForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({url: "api.php", dataType: "json", data: data, type: "POST", success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            window.location.href = 'thank-you.php';
        }});
    });
```

Is it possible to have replace the window.location.href with a post call so I can pass data to this thank you page? So basically for form does the action but only after my ajax call is successful.

What I am trying to do is on submit, make my ajax call and when its successful goto thank-you.php with the post data.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do... You need to explain it better

Comment: Updated my question, I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Can you explain @Alivetodie-Anant

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415740/jquery-resume-form-submit-after-ajax-call

Comment: do it like this: `$('form').attr('action', 'thank-you.php').off('submit').submit();`