# Resubmit form after an ajax request is made to a url different from the form url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is a part code from a project I'm working on. I want to save the form data by an ajax call to a url `/accounts/edit_profile/` (different from the form action url `/orders/place_order/`). After a successful call to url `/accounts/edit_profile/`, form should resubmit to `orders/place_order/` but no such resubmission takes place and I have to manually click the button (`place_order`) for final submission of form.

```
<form id="form_check" action="/orders/place_order/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="">Address line 1</label>
      <input type="text" name="address_line_1" class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="">Address line 2</label>
      <input type="text" name="address_line_2" class="form-control" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="">State</label>
      <input type="text" name="state" class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="">Pincode</label>
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{6}" name="pincode" class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label for="">Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btnsubmit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Place Order</button>
</form>
```

The script I'm using is:

```
var frm = $('#form_check');
frm.submit(function() {
  var r = confirm("Would you like to save this address as default address?");
  if (r == true) {
    $.ajax({
      type: frm.attr('method'),
      url: '/accounts/edit_profile/',
      data: frm.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        frm.submit();
      }
    });
  } else {
    // user did not agree, do something else
  }
  return false;
});
```

Tried Soultions from these links but nothing seems to work:

- [**jQuery - Resume form submit after ajax cal**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415740/jquery-resume-form-submit-after-ajax-call)
- [**Resume form submission after $.ajax call**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185431/resume-form-submission-after-ajax-call)

Comment: Use `frm[0].submit()`. By using the jQuery object you're just calling your submit handler again.

Comment: 'frm[0].submit()' Not working

Comment: See the linked question for the recommended solutions (except the ones that suggest `async: false`, which is deprecated).

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it myself. Here's the solution:

Comment: I've reopened, you can post the solution below. Or maybe you should post it in one of the other questions, if those solutions don't work.

Comment: I have updated the form code above by adding a new `id='btnsubmit'` in submit button of form. Inside ajax success code, I added `frm.off('submit');` and then `$('#btnsubmit').click();`

Comment: Post the solution in an Answer, not the Question.

Comment: Here's the solution. Inside the jquery ajax success function, update this code `success: function (data) {
        frm.off('submit');
        $('#btnsubmit').click();
      }`

Comment: `frm.off('submit'); frm.submit()` should do the same thing.

Comment: Put the solution in an Answer below, not a comment.

Comment: `frm.submit();` will go through the whole process by asking the question again and will not submit the form finally. This is the problem I was facing

Comment: No it won't, because `frm.off("submit")` disables that.

Comment: You're right. I checked it again and it worked. Thanks for commenting